# How can I make only the button selectable in a cell?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have a Cell with lots of Labels and a Button.

I want to make cell's color blue and make *only* the button selectable, not the cell.

The button should have its own color.

How can I do this using with xCode and the IPhone SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

implement the following method in your UITableViewController:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Then return nil for any cell that you do not want selectable (Your cells with buttons). You can get additionaly explanation from the UITableViewDelegate protocol reference.

From the UItableViewDelegate protocol reference:

> -(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath
>   *)indexPath
>
> **Parameters** tableView A table-view
>   object informing the delegate about
>   the impending selection.
>
> **indexPath** An index path locating the
>   row in tableView.
>
> **Return Value** An index-path object that
>   confirms or alters the selected row.
>   Return an NSIndexPath object other
>   than indexPath if you want another
>   cell to be selected. **Return nil if you
>   don't want the row selected.**
>
> **Discussion** This method is not called
>   until users touch a row and then lift
>   their finger; the row isn't selected
>   until then, although it is highlighted
>   on touch-down. You can use
>   UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone to
>   disable the appearance of the cell
>   highlight on touch-down.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "does not work". Cna you be more descriptive? Make sure your UITableViewController is set as the delegate for the UITableView. Set a breakpoint and make sure you are getting inside the method.
It might help if you can post some code.